# SQL column update to solve data quality issue

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am unable to figure out how to write 'smart code' for this. [image: problem sample]

In this case I would like the end result for the first two case to be:

**product_cat_name**

A_SEE

A_BEE

Business is rule is such that one `product_cat_name` can belong to only one `group` but due to data quality issues we sometimes have a `product_cat_name` belonging to 2 different `group`s. As a special case in such a situation we would like to append `group` to the `product_cat_name` so that `product_cat_name` becomes unique.

It sounds so simple yet I am cracking my head over this.
Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Are you planning to update the data, or do you just want a query that will give you the data in this form?

Comment: You need to provide some information here. See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create an example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) You haven't even asked a question, just stated the requirements vaguely.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
with names as (

    select prod_cat_nm , prod_cat_nm+group as new_nm from (query that joins 3 tables together) as qry
    join
    (Select prod_cat_nm,  count(distinct group)
    from (query that joins 3 tables together) as x
    group by 
    prod_cat_nm
    having count(distinct group) > 1) dups
    on dups.prod_cat_nm = qry.prod_cat_nm
    )

    SELECT prod_cat_nm, STRING_AGG(New_nm, '') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY New_Nm ASC) AS new_prod_cat_nm
    FROM names
    GROUP BY prod_cat_nm;
```

I've used the 2017 STRING_AGG() here as its shortest to write - But you could easily change this to use Recursions or XML path

Answer (score 0):

It is simple if you break it down into small pieces.

You need to UPDATE the table obviously, and change the value of `product_cat_name`.   That's easy.

The new value should be `group + product_cat_name`.  That's easy.

You only want to do this when a `product_cat_name` is associated with more than one group.  That's probably the tricky part, but it can also be broken down into small pieces that are easy.

You need to identify which `product_cat_name`s have more than one group.  That's easy.  `GROUP BY product_cat_name HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Group) > 1`.

Now you need to use that to limit your UPDATE to only those `product_cat_name`s.  That's easy.  `WHERE product_cat_name IN (Subquery using above logic to get PCNs that have more than one Group)`.

All easy steps.  Put them together and you've got your solution.